# How to do getter and setter in array list in Android

Tags: java, android

I have created two class.  One of which has reference to another:

```
public class SCHOOL {

    private String schoolid;
    private String schoolname;
    private List<STUDENT> students;

    //getter and setter for schooled and schoolname

    public void setStudents(List<STUDENT> students) {
        this.students = students;
    }

    public List<STUDENT> getStudents() {
        return this.students;
    }
}

public class STUDENT {

    private String names;
    private String age;


    public String getNames() {
        return names;
    }
    public void setNames(String names) {
        this.names = names;
    }

    public String getAge() {
        return age;
    }
    public void setAge(String age) {
        this.age = age;
    }
}
```

In my Main Activity I use the following to create the array:

```
  ...
  List<STUDENT> studentList = new ArrayList<>();
  STUDENT student1 = new STUDENT();
    student1.setNames("Kent");
    ....
  STUDENT student2 = new STUDENT();
    student2.setNames("Winnie");
    ...

  studentList.add(student1);
  studentList.add(student2);
```

My question is that is there any way set and get data using "setStudents"
to input data and List getStudents() to get data?  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just call set with the `List` you have created or return a new one by calling get:

```
SCHOOL school = new SCHOOL();
school.setStudents(studentList);

List<STUDENT> students = school.getStudents();
```

You could also input data directly to a `SCHOOL` class with such a method

```
public void addStudent(STUDENT student) {
    students.add(student);
}
```

or this one where you don't have to create a STUDENT yourself

```
public void addStudent(String names, int age) {
    STUDENT student = new STUDENT();        
    student.setNames(names);
    student.setAge(age);
    students.add(student);
}
```

you would need and index to get a `STUDENT` from a `SCHOOL`

```
public STUDENT getStudent(int index) {
    return students.get(index);
}
```